# Remove multiple instances of the same person, different IDs from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set where there are individuals appearning multiple times with the same name and SSN but different personids.  I want to remove those people and only keep those that appear one time.

```
    declare @t table(personid int, first_name varchar(50), last_name varchar(50), ssn int)
    insert into @t
    values(1, 'Roman', 'Smith', 12),
    (2, 'John', 'Thomas', 15),
    (3, 'John', 'Thomas', 15)
```

In this instance I only want to return Roman Smith and eliminate John Thomas altogether.

I've been playing around with Window Functions and I've only managed to get this far:

```
    select * from
    (
    select person_id, first_name, last_name, middle_initial, ssn,
    row_number() over(partition by ssn, first_name, last_name, middle_initial order by person_id) as 
    rn
    from t_person
    where person_id in (1, 2, 3)
    )a
    where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario I like to use [NOT EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Easy way to perform elimination.

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t AS T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE ssn = T.ssn GROUP BY ssn HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Aside: The `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` list is superfluous typing. In a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` subquery, the select list is disregarded by the SQL engine. (Run the query using `SELECT 1/0...` to see. Same results, no errors.) `SELECT 1` gets the job done with fewer keystrokes, and makes clear that you're not using/expecting any results from the query. That said, this is the approach I would use, too. +1

Comment: @EricBrandt Great point! Updated my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use a `window function`, here is one way to do it..

```
select personid, first_name, last_name, ssn
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by first_name, last_name, ssn) freq from @t) a 
where freq=1;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17d905007c1ba85ef5dda70edd8550fe)

Comment: This gives an error that Person_ID is invalid because it is not contained in the aggregate function or GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @jackstraw22 Sorry I didn't think that through. You already have a great answer, but I added this so you can see how you could have modified your approach to get the result you wanted.

Comment: That's good to see.  I like to know that I was on the right path with what I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT max(person_id) person_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       ssn
       FROM @t
       GROUP BY first_name,
                last_name,
                ssn
       HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'LIKE' operator to get all the names that match a given pattern and remove them altogether from your database.

DELETE FROM table name

WHERE first_name LIKE '%$name%'

This will remove all the instances of the given 'name', however, this can only be used if you already have an idea of the repeated data.

Comment: I was just providing sample data.  Using LIKE with a million records would take forever.

Comment: It would, I myself wouldn't suggest this if you have large amount of repetitions!